# Confirmation Box [OK] & [CANCEL] before PHP Delete Query

Tags: javascript, php, sql-delete

Good day! In my code below deletes the selected value instantly. My concern is... I want to have a confirmation box with `continue` to delete & `cancel` to stop the action proceeding into the `delete query`.

How do I do it? Thank you for the help!

```html
<?php if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
  $categoryID = $_POST['categoryID'];

  $delsql="DELETE FROM category WHERE categoryID=".$categoryID;
 $delquery=mysqli_query($con, $delsql);
 
 $stock_sql="DELETE FROM post WHERE categoryID=".$categoryID;
 $stock_query=mysqli_query($con, $stock_sql);
}

?>


<form class="add-new-post" method="post" action="deletecategoryselect.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Choose Category: <br><br>
  <select  ng-model='discussionsSelect' class='form-control' name="categoryID" >
        <?php do { ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $delcat_rs['categoryID']; ?>">
            <?php echo $delcat_rs['name']; ?></option> 
        <?php } while ($delcat_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($delcat_query));?>
      </select>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-2x" name="delete">Delete</button>

 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change submit event. I've used confirm  here, but basicly you can use any logic you want, just stick with *event.preventDefault()* and *form.submit()*.

```
//select form any way you want
const form = document.getElementById('formName');

form.onsubmit = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const test = confirm('Do you want to delete this?');
    if (test === true) {
        form.submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like below.

Add `onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');"` to the button `<button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" class="btn btn-primary btn-2x" name="delete">Delete</button>`

The confirm dialog will show `OK` and `Cancel` button and returns `true` if the user clicked `OK`. return `false` otherwise and it will prevent form submit.